# Where is the full rank property used here?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a real positive definite matrix of order $n$. I have to prove if $X$ is a full rank real matrix of order $n$, then $X^T A X$ is positive definite.

I did it this way —
$X^T A X$ is p.d.
$\iff \langle X^T A X v, v \rangle > 0$ for some non-zero $v$
$\iff \langle A X v, X v \rangle > 0$
$\iff \langle A y, y \rangle > 0$ where $y=Xv$,
which is true, since $A$ is positive definite.
So $X^T A X$ is positive definite.

But where is $X$ being full rank being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need it to guarantee, that for any $v\neq 0$ also $y=Xv \neq 0$.

Comment: Ah yes. Got it. Thank you.

Comment: So there’s no situation when $X$ is full rank, and $v$ is non-zero that the product $Xv$ will be non zero? I get it intuitively but a proof would be helpful.

Comment: If $X$ has full rank, then it is invertible and hence injective.

Comment: Can I say it like this — Suppose $Xv = 0$ and $X$ is full rank, $v$ is non zero. Then it means $v$ belongs to $null X$, which means dim null $X \geq 1$ but dim null $X = n-rank(X) = n-n=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, for example.